# How does EVE Central get the market data?

Tags: eve-online

[EVE Central](http://eve-central.com/) is a well known site for checking buy and sell orders. How do they get all the information about current market orders?

I know there is an
[API](http://community.eveonline.com), but this is restricted to the Character/Corporation information only. I know there is static [CCP Static Data Export](http://wiki.eve-id.net/CCP_Static_Data_Export)
but I do not see buy/sell orders there.

Comment: I don't think "How to build a website" is on topic for this website.

Comment: @MattEllen I agree, but this is not the case. EVE has a focus on economy, in my opinion, this is game related.

Comment: @MattEllen EvE is a lot of different from other MMORPG games. Lots of players spend more time out of a game harvesting informations than in the game itself. Knowledge is power and can buy you a PLEX if you know how to use it.

Comment: Before the edits you asked how to build a website. That seemed to me like the main thrust of your question. "How do I build a website around an API?" is a very different question to "How does EVE Central get the market data?". That's why I commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EVE Central works by showing market details from data scraped from the markets throughout the game. This data is then uploaded by users using EVEMon or Contribtastic. The time since the market data for a particular entry on EVE Central is shown in the search results on the right most column - "Reported Time".

Comment: When he says scraped data, he means that there is a program that runs (contribtastic) that will look through the cached data files in your eve game folder. It decodes it, then uploads it the data to EVE Central for you and everyone else to see.